# Lebesgue (Borel) measurability according to Avner Friedman

Tags: measure-theory, definition, lebesgue-measure

On page 29 in *Foundations of Modern Analysis* Friedman writes roughly:

> $f$ is measurable if the inverse image of any open set in $R^1$ is measurable. When $X$ is the Lebesgue (Borel) space, then we say that $f$ is Lebesgue (Borel) measurable on $X$.

He writes this without even labeling it as a definition, and I struggle to see how this is equivalent to the wiki definition "$f$ is measurable if the pre-image of every measurable set is measurable". Is it enough to check for the open sets to see that it is so for all measurable sets?

I interpret Lebesgue (Borel) measurability then as saying all L (B)-measurable sets is mapped by the inverse to a L (B)-measurable set, right? I'm confused.

Comment: Borel sets are generated by open sets. So every measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ can be "pieced together" from open sets, and the ways we piece these sets together transfers to the pre-image. Something similar can be done for Lebesgue-measurable sets.

Comment: If $(X,\mathcal{M})$ is a measurable space and $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is a function, then $f$ is measurable if $f^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal{M}$ for every Borel set $B\subset\mathbb{R}$. Note that $B$ is only assumed to be a Borel set, not a Lebesgue measurable set. This is important because the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra is strictly larger than the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Okey @AJY, thank you. I thought so. I have found examples of a functions that map e.g. the Cantor set to an open set but there is a subset (Vitali) set that doesn't map to an L-set. Is it so that the check for every open set would not work for any such map?

Comment: @carmichael561 But for $f$ to be L-measurable we would need to check for all L-sets? Or Borel is enough?

Comment: To say that $f$ is Lebesgue measurable means that $X$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{M}$ is the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra. So it's still enough to check Borel sets.

Comment: Friedman has the standard definition.  WIki has somebody's idea of a definition.  As noted, you need to use the Borel sets of $R^1$ in the Wiki definition for the two definitions to agree.